# How to get users location using a class in android getting null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, location

I am using a separate class to get user's location. How to get user's location by calling interface in my activity.I cant understand How can i get user's location' latitude and longitude in my activity? It is giving me null pointer exception when i create object of class and call method

My Activity

```
public class missingPerson extends AppCompatActivity implements OnLocationUpdateListener {

OnLocationUpdateListener lu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_missing_person);
    final LocationHandler locationHandler = new LocationHandler(missingPerson.this,lu);
    locationHandler.getDeviceLocation();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  Location location1 = location;

    String latitute = String.valueOf(location1.getLatitude());
    Log.i("No Result", latitute);

 }

@Override
public void onError(String error) {

 }
}
```

Class for location

```
package com.example.fizatanveerkhan.citycops;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import java.util.List;

public class LocationHandler {
private Activity activity;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
private Location mLastKnownLocation;
private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private OnLocationUpdateListener onLocationUpdateListener;
private boolean updateStartedInternally = false;
private boolean isconnected = false;

public LocationHandler(Activity activity, final OnLocationUpdateListener onLocationUpdateListener) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.onLocationUpdateListener = onLocationUpdateListener;
    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity);
    createLocationRequest();
    getDeviceLocation();

    mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            List<Location> locationList = locationResult.getLocations();
            if (locationList.size() > 0) {
                //The last location in the list is the newest
                Location location = locationList.get(locationList.size() - 1);
                mLastKnownLocation = location;

                if (onLocationUpdateListener != null) {
                    onLocationUpdateListener.onLocationChanged(location);
                    if(updateStartedInternally){
                        stopLocationUpdate();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}


public boolean isConnected() {
    return isconnected;
}

public void getDeviceLocation() {
    /*
     * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
     * cases when a location is not available.
     */
    try {

        Task locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();

       locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(activity, new OnCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                isconnected = true;
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                    mLastKnownLocation = (Location) task.getResult();
                    if (mLastKnownLocation == null) {
                        updateStartedInternally = true;
                        mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                    } else if (mLastKnownLocation != null){

                        mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());

       // This message appears in logcat with latitute still it say that 
    // onLocationUpdateListener.onLocationChanged is invoked on null object 
     //   reference 


                        Log.e("Location", String.valueOf(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude()));
                        onLocationUpdateListener.onLocationChanged(mLastKnownLocation);

                    }
                }
                else {
                    onLocationUpdateListener.onError("Can't get Location");
                }
            }
        }) ;

    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        onLocationUpdateListener.onError(e.getMessage());

    }
}

public void startLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    updateStartedInternally = false;
    mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
}

private void stopLocationUpdate() {
    mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
}


//other new Methods but not using right now..
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);//set the interval in which you want to get locations
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);//if a location is available sooner you can get it (i.e. another app is using the location services)
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
  }
 }
```

And this is Interface

```
 import android.location.Location;

 public interface OnLocationUpdateListener {
   void onLocationChanged(Location location);
   void onError(String error)
 }
```

Error

```
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 4848 bytes, containing 1 windows, 15 views
E/Location: 37.4219983
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.fizatanveerkhan.citycops, PID: 14006
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void 
    com.example.fizatanveerkhan 
   .citycops.OnLocationUpdateListener.onLocationChanged
   (android.location.Location)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.fizatanveerkhan.citycops.
   LocationHandler$2.onComplete(LocationHandler.java:88)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os
    .RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
       I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14006 SIG: 9
    Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final LocationHandler locationHandler = new LocationHandler(missingPerson.this,lu);
```

What is this "lu" that you pass as second argument during instance? I don't see it anywhere.

```
public LocationHandler(Activity activity, final OnLocationUpdateListener onLocationUpdateListener) { 
//........
}
```

LocationHandler take OnLocationUpdateListener and set

```
this.onLocationUpdateListener = onLocationUpdateListener;
```

Then, you call

```
onLocationUpdateListener.onLocationChanged(mLastKnownLocation);
```

If you pass "lu" (that maybe is null), is pretty clear that object's onLocationUpdateListener is null.

Comment: Sorry i missed posting this line   OnLocationUpdateListener lu; here in question edited the question now error is not because of this